# How to interpret the outcome tables of a naive Bayes classifier

Tags: r, classification, naive-bayes, bayesian-network

I have calculated a Naive Bayes with the klaR package.  The vector "RandomAssignment" is representing the 7 Categories. "ydf" is a data frame which represents the underlying data.

```
m  <-  NaiveBayes(as.factor(RandomAssignment) ~ ., data = ydf)
```

Now I get the following output tables.  Can someone interpret my output?

Output $tables gives me 23 tables. One of the tables looks like in the following example:

```
$tables$CASH
      [,1]     [,2]
1 18.05122 1.155268
2 16.78024 1.738871
3 18.38182 1.003076
4 18.10533 1.347283
5 18.56694 3.707506
6 18.22490 1.487361
7 18.55957 2.067211
```

Furthermore I received a table "$x" which has equal size as the underlying dataset (55X23). It is filled with positiv rational numbers between 5 and 25. How can I interpret this table?

Additional hint:

I have 23 predictors, 7 categories and 55 observations. In the End I will have ~1000 observations,  but I have not yet included them due to performance reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you do not provide your data, I cannot demonstrate with that. 
Instead, I will illustrate the meaning of the tables using the 
iris dataset.

```
library(klaR)
IrisNB = NaiveBayes(Species ~ ., data=iris)
names(IrisNB)
[1] "apriori"  "tables"  "levels"  "call"  "x" "usekernel" "varnames"
```

you asked about two parts of the returned result: `tables` and `x`.

`x` is the simplest.  It is just a copy of the original data that you provided 
to NaiveBayes to build the model.

```
head(IrisNB$x)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4

head(iris[,1:4])
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
```

`tables` is the more interesting part. In order to explain that, 
I must first explain a little about how the Naïve Bayes prediction
is computed.

Given a point (x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>) we wish to predict which class this 
point should be. To do that, for each possible class, c, we will compute 
P(c| x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub>) 
and choose the class with the biggest probability. 
Using Bayes Law we can rewrite this as

> P(c| x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub>) = 
>   P(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub> | c) * P(c) / 
>   P(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub>)

Since the denominator, P(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub>), 
is the same no matter what the class, to maximize the entire expression, we need only maximize the numerator,
P(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub> | c) * P(c). 
Now here comes the "Naïve" part. We make 
the assumption that the x<sub>i</sub>'s are conditionally independent, i.e. we assume

P(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub> | c)
= P(x<sub>1</sub>|c) * P(x<sub>2</sub>|c) * ... * P(x<sub>n</sub>|c)

While this assumption is rarely correct,  it makes computation easier and 
we usually can make much more reliable estimates of the P(x<sub>i</sub>|c) than
we can for P(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub> | c)

OK, so now we need to estimate each of the P(x<sub>i</sub>|c). *THAT* is what the `tables` 
are for. If you look at the tables,  you will see that for every variable 
(4 for the iris data, 23 for your data)  there is a table with two columns 
and one row for each of the potential classes (3 for the iris data, 7 for 
your data).

Here is one of the tables from the iris data.

```
IrisNB$tables$Sepal.Length
            [,1]      [,2]
setosa     5.006 0.3524897
versicolor 5.936 0.5161711
virginica  6.588 0.6358796
```

(setosa, versicolor and virginica are the three classes for the iris data.)
The first column is the mean for iris$Sepal.Length when grouped by the class.

```
aggregate(iris$Sepal.Length, list(iris$Species), mean)
     Group.1     x
1     setosa 5.006
2 versicolor 5.936
3  virginica 6.588
```

The second column is the standard deviation for the data grouped by class.

```
aggregate(iris$Sepal.Length, list(iris$Species), sd)
     Group.1         x
1     setosa 0.3524897
2 versicolor 0.5161711
3  virginica 0.6358796
```

The idea is that we are going to assume that the data for each class is
normally distributed and so knowing the mean and standard deviation, 
we can compute the probability of any given value, that is, we can compute
P(x<sub>i</sub>|c).  Since we can do this for each variable, we can compute

P(x<sub>1</sub>|c) * P(x<sub>2</sub>|c) * ... * P(x<sub>n</sub>|c) 
using these Gaussian estimates from the data.

For completeness,  I will explain one more piece of the output, `apriori`. 
Recall that we needed a little bit more for our probability estimate.  The 
numerator that we wished to maximize is actually

P(x<sub>1</sub>|c) * P(x<sub>2</sub>|c) * ... * P(x<sub>n</sub>|c) * P(c)

We also need P(c), the prior. Of course, for each class, that is just 
the number of points with that class, divided by the total number of points. 
That exactly matches the information in the `apriori` variable.

```
IrisNB$apriori
grouping
    setosa versicolor  virginica 
 0.3333333  0.3333333  0.3333333 

table(iris$Species)/nrow(iris)
    setosa versicolor  virginica 
 0.3333333  0.3333333  0.3333333
```

To summarize,

`x` is just the original data.

`tables` provides the mean and standard deviation of the data grouped by class so that we can estimate the probabilities P(x<sub>i</sub>|c) 
on the assumption that each of these can be represented by a Gaussian distribution.

`apriori` gives the priors P(c)